# how to write delta symbol in a question

Tags: support

well I am having this problem while trying to write delta symbol in the question box. I have tries using two $ signs and delta between them. but nothing happened. Please help.

Comment: Did you use [backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash)?

Comment: no! Is it like $\delta$

Comment: Yes, now try it [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Does it work?

Comment: yes it is working. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It is like `$\delta$` or `$\Delta$` for capital.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation for details .

And https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

And  **http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html**

Comment: I'm guessing you left out the backslashes by accident so I edited them in.